# Reduce an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have created FormArray where I compose order items.
JSON which is generated from Form is like this.

```
{
   "validFrom":"2018-11-16T21:07:02.167Z",
   "validTo":"2018-12-01T21:07:02.167Z",
   "totalPriceOfOrder": "{{Price of all items this need be calculated from all child object total price}}"
   "items":[
      {
         "name":"Head Phones",
         "unit":"",
         "quantity":"1",
         "price":"200",
         "totalPrice":""
      },
      {
         "name":"",
         "unit":"",
         "quantity":"2",
         "price":"200",
         "totalPrice":""
      }
   ]
}
```

I need in Items array calculate:
1. quantity * price = totalPrice
For example

```
{
         "name":"",
         "unit":"",
         "quantity":"3",
         "price":"200",
         "totalPrice":"600"
}
```

Then I need all totalPrices of Items array add up to parent propertytotalPriceOfOrder.

I have tried with reduce, but unsuccessfully.
Could you please give me example or advice

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you need to use RxJS? Can you show us your reduce code?

Comment: "I have tried with reduce, but unsuccessfully." What did you try, and how was it unsuccessful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be pretty easy -

```
 let propertytotalPriceOfOrder = order.items.map(item => +item.unit * +item.quantity * +item.price);
```

where `order` is your entire json object.

Note : `+` operator is used since you have `string` value in json which needs to be converted to `number` before `arithmetic` calculation.